# Setting git upstream to a windows server

Tags: windows, git

I am junior in a small business trying to setup a Git server for a team of 3 programmers.

They want the code to be visible in a folder and easily accessible and finally hosted on a Windows server.
Hence they want to stay away from solutions like gitea or bonobo.

Here is a link of what I'm trying to accomplish, but on windows.[Setting up git server on linux](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server).

Answer (score 0):

A [Gitea server](https://gitea.com/) remains the simplest setup (one database+one `gitea` executable, and you are good to go, even  on Windows)

You can then associate to your Gitea-hosted repository a [post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) that will checkout said repository to a local folder on your server, in a shared and accessible directory, if your Gitea server is directly on Windows.

Or the same post-receive hook can create an [archive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive), and scp it to a Windows server (if you used a Linux server, assuming an openSSH daemon is set on Windows side, or an UNC shared folder is available), and uncompress said archive in the deployment folder.

But the idea remains: a hook can take care of the "visible in a folder and easily accessible".

Answer (score 0):

[SCM Manager](https://scm-manager.org/docs/2.30.x/en/installation/windows/) can be the easiest way to get managed Git-server for any OS (Windows too)

> the code to be visible in a folder and easily accessible

This statement has to be rewritten, if you want to have more definitive answers